# What does "0b" and "0x" stand for when assigning binary and hex?

Tags: c++, binary, hex

When assigning a binary value and a hexadecimal value directly you can do it as follows (respectively):

```
uint8_t val1 = 0b10101;
uint8_t val2 = 0xFF;
```

What does the `0b` and `0x` mean? Specifically the 0 at the front. Can you have other values instead of `0`?

Also as another curious question, what other characters can go in the place of `b` and `x`? Is there one for octal as an example?

Comment: _"Is there one for octal as an example?"_ Sure that's just a `0` prefix.

Comment: Intuitively, "b" is for ***b***inary and "x" for he***x***.

Comment: these numbers are called "literals" and if you google you'll see all the literal syntax prefixes/suffixes.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: "x" is "exadecimal", because programming languages used to be manufactured exclusively in Manchester.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any and all integer literals you can create are summarized in the C++ standard by the grammar production at [[lex.icon]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.icon)

> ```
> integer-literal:
>     binary-literal integer-suffixopt
>     octal-literal integer-suffixopt
>     decimal-literal integer-suffixopt
>     hexadecimal-literal integer-suffixopt
>
> binary-literal:
>     0b binary-digit
>     0B binary-digit
>     binary-literal 'opt binary-digit
>
> octal-literal:
>     0
>     octal-literal 'opt octal-digit
>
> decimal-literal:
>     nonzero-digit
>     decimal-literal 'opt digit
>
> hexadecimal-literal:
>     hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-digit-sequence
>
> binary-digit:
>     0
>     1
>
> octal-digit: one of
>     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
>
> nonzero-digit: one of
>     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
>
> hexadecimal-prefix: one of
>     0x  0X
>
> hexadecimal-digit-sequence:
>     hexadecimal-digit
>     hexadecimal-digit-sequence 'opt hexadecimal-digit
>
> hexadecimal-digit: one of
>     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
>     a  b  c  d  e  f
>     A  B  C  D  E  F
> ```

As we can deduce from the grammar, there are four types of integer literals:

- Plain decimal, that must begin with a non-zero digit.
- Octal, any number with a leading 0 (including a plain 0).
- Binary, requiring the prefix `0b` or `0B`.
- Hexadecimal, requiring the prefix `0x` or `0X`.

The leading 0 for octal numbers can be thought of as the "O" in "Octal". The other prefixes use a leading zero to mark the beginning of a number that should not be interpreted as decimal. "B" is intuitively for "**b**inary", while "X" is for "he**x**adecimal".

Comment: Given you've taken the "standard" route, you might want to mention things like `\123`.

Comment: @Bathsheba - `'\123'` is not strictly valid. One can only have octal and hex escape sequence. Also, since the issue at hand is integer literals, I feel personally that bringing character literals into scope can be confusing. Two monstrous grammar productions in a single answer feels like too much to me.

Comment: Why 0x chosen, instead of 0h? And 0o is better than 0, isn't it?

Comment: @DawnSong - Phonetically, the X stands out more than the H. Plus, the o seems redundant. In certain jargon, o and 0 are used interchangeably. `08:00` might be referred to as "oh eighthundred hours" for instance.

Answer (score 4):

`0b` (or `0B`) denotes a *binary literal*. C++ has allowed it since C++14. (It's not part of the C standard yet although some compilers allow it as an extension.) `0x` (or `0X`) is for *hexadecimal*.

`0` can be used to denote an *octal literal*. (Interestingly `0` itself is an octal literal). Furthermore you use the *escape sequence* `\` followed by digits to be read in octal: this applies only when defining `const char[]` literals using `""` or `char` or multicharacter literals using `''`. The `'\0'` notation that you often see to denote NUL when working with strings exploits that.

In the absence of a *user defined literal* suffix, any numeric literal starting with a non-zero is in denary.

There are rumblings in the C++ world to use `0o` for an octal literal and perhaps even drop support for the leading zero version. Although that would be an hideous breaking change.

Comment: @Angew: Indeed, I've spelt it out. You can use them in funnies such as multicharacter constants too, although that one could be for the pub quiz.

Comment: In short, they're a type of character escape sequence, and not an integer literal.

Answer (score 2):

> What does the 0b and 0x mean?

They mean that the nuneric literal is respectively in binary and hexadecimal base.

> Can you have other values instead of 0?

A numeric literal starting with a non zero digit will be a decimal literal.

> Also as another curious question, what other characters can go in the place of "b" and "x"?

Besides b and x, any octal digit can go there in which case it is the most significant digit of an octal literal.