# typedef enum with binary definitions error (IAR 8.40)

Tags: c, enums, iar

When developing the firmware for STM32 in IAR, I encountered the following:

```
typedef enum ll{
  A = 0b00000000000000000000000000000000,
  B = 0b00000000000000000000000000000011,
} lol;
```

***Error[Pe067]: expected a "}" PROJ\Core\Src\main.c 72*** (2d line)

But,

```
typedef enum ll{
  A = 0x00000000,
  B = 0x11111111,
} lol;
```

is compile successfully.
I know all of this code work in another IDE n compilers.
But what happens in my case? Why number with 0b brings errors? Maybe needed set some configure for compiler?

Comment: Note that the `0b` prefix for binary numbers is not a standard part of the C language, but some implementations support it as an extension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "0b" and "0x" stand for when assigning binary and hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605226/what-does-0b-and-0x-stand-for-when-assigning-binary-and-hex)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't C have binary literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244726/why-doesnt-c-have-binary-literals)

Comment: The working draft of the next version of the C standard (C23) does have these binary literals.

Comment: IAR does not support binary constans.

Comment: This is mentioned in IAR's [Technical Note 46979](https://www.iar.com/knowledge/support/technical-notes/compiler/any-binary-notation-in-c-source/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary literals (i.e. integers with the `0b` prefix, such as `0b010101`) are *not* part of the (standard) C language. However, they *are* part of C++ (since C++14), and some compilers (notably GCC) support them as an extension in C.

Answer (score 1):

IAR does not support binary constants as they are not the part of the C standard.